# Matrix library for large matrices?

Tags: c++, windows, matrix, linear-algebra

Is there any C++ matrix library for large matrices(matrices that can't fit in RAM)?

Or maybe some library that is designed to handle with large matrices and more faster relative to basic matrix libraries?

I think Windows can handle such matrices by using swap file, but maybe there is optimized algorithms for this?

I found [ScaLAPACK](http://www.netlib.org/scalapack/) but not sure it's the best choice.

Comment: are you taking about a single matrix not fitting in ram?

Comment: How big can it grow? What is the upper bound?

Comment: if it can fit in ram, you would be talking about more than a billion units ( 8gb ). if it were otherwise a smaller large matrix, have you heard about cuda? you can always save matrices on disk manually

Comment: I don't know about the size of matrix, but for example I have 8Gb of RAM and using matlab I get out of memory(if I use swap file it takes too long), also I want my program can work on 2Gb RAM machine also. For example I need such operation as calculate SVD.

Comment: Also I heard about CUDA but GPU have even smaller amout of memory about 1 Gb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [block matrix multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_matrix_multiplication) and [inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Blockwise_inversion) in order to reduce swapping.

If your matrices are [sparse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix) (i.e. they have a lot of elements that are zero), you can save memory by using a special storage approach.

Comment: In particular, [eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TutorialSparse.html) library has some features to work with sparse matrices.